# Where do I go to add text to the customer account login page on my site?

Tags: backend, forms, login

Where do I go to add text to the customer account login page on my site? I have not worked in Magento previously and I am not finding this option when logging into the admin panel.

http://theh2oguru.com/customer/account/login/

I am not finding this through the CMS. Also, I do not have access to the ftp, but have asked for it.

I am used to working within WordPress for what it's worth.

Thanks very much for a response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable template hints for the current store ( google for magento template hints ). It's magento feature that show admin the page structure with the path to the templates.

Then you can open the template file by ftp and insert the text.

Comment: Thanks! I am waiting for FTP access right now. I appreciate your response.

Comment: I will be glad if you accept the answer if it was helpful ;) do not hesitate to ask for any clarification if needed.